# Pointing To Android Directory

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to convert an image to byte using c# and parsing the byte to a web service but I have this line of code I just can't get right. I am trying to point to a phone's storage path, pictures in my device and I can't seem to get the correct path.

```
byte[] imageByte = Environment.GetExternalStorageDirectory().getPath( "FAMScanner\\Vehicle_{0}.jpg");
```

Comment: You know that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` returns a `String` right? Not a `byte[]`...

Comment: I'm curious. Isn't it *more* bothersome to capitalize every single word, rather than do what everyone else does and use sentence-casing?

Comment: What is `sentence-casing` ? I do not see capitalized words. So i cannot even ask who is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest converting the image to a bitmap object first. Because that way you can use the following answer from another similar question.

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513976/how-to-convert-image-into-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-base64-string-in-android)

To create a bitmap object you'll need to get the path to your image file first and then create it like that:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys but i found the solution to my problem.

byte[] imageByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/image.jpg");

thats all i needed to do to point directly to my android storage device in order to convert my image into a byte[] and parse it on a web service to a database.