# PHP - How to convert byte array to image file?

Tags: java, php, jpeg

Using Java SDK i have JPEG byte array. Now using PHP i need to show that byte array into JPEG picture using  tag.

How can i convert byte array to readable JPEG? Tried this but its not showing the picture at all.

```
$byteArray = "[A@53d9e469"; //something like this Java generated
$img = "<img src= 'data:image/jpeg;base64, $byteArray' />";
echo ($img);
```

EDIT:

I have tried $byteArray = base64_encode($byteArray);  but that is not working.

Comment: try
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: Tried this $byteArray = base64_encode($byteArray); but no image showing still.

Comment: This is not working too: String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(someImg), 
                       Base64.NO_WRAP);

Answer (score 0):

make sure you go from bytes array to base 64. see:
[How to convert image into byte array and byte array to base64 String in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513976/how-to-convert-image-into-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-base64-string-in-android)

Comment: This is not for Android. this is not working `String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(someImg), 
                       Base64.NO_WRAP);`