# I need to parse images array to json with GSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

The method where I get the images

```
private List<HashMap<String, RequestBody>> getUserDocumentsPhoto(File[] images){

    HashMap<String, RequestBody> userDocumentsPhoto = new HashMap<>();
    List<HashMap<String, RequestBody>> photos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (File image : images) {
        RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), image);
        userDocumentsPhoto.put("filename=\"" + image.getName(), fileBody);
    }
    photos.add(userDocumentsPhoto);
    return photos;
```

When parse to json I need to get

```
"document_photos": [
"/system/attachments/files/000/000/110/original/photo20160726_120701-1392731703.jpg?1469524104",
"/system/attachments/files/000/000/111/original/photo20160726_120814-2041790628.jpg?1469524105"]
```

But when it parsed, "document_photos []" has null

Comment: when HashMap parse to json, "document_photos" has null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create model class. Which the structure of this class is like this:

```
public class Model {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

and your activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Model model = new Model();
        model.getItems().add("first");
        model.getItems().add("second");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(model);
        Log.e("json",json);
    }
}
```

Add **Gson** library in your `build.gradle` as dependency.

Comment: How can I parse image file to String and put it into List<String> ?

Comment: you can parse image to byte format and then put it List<byte[]>

Comment: for parsing you can look up this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513976/how-to-convert-image-into-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-base64-string-in-android