# How to convert image into byte array and byte array to base 64 string in android?

Tags: android, asp.net, arrays, json

Can someone tell me the code to convert image into byte array and that byte array into base64 string. i write the below code not getting proper result .

```
 String filepath = "/sdcard/Image/ic_launcher.jpg";
   File imagefile = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , baos);    
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

result im getting is

```
[-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 72, 0, 72, 0, 0, -1, -20, 4, -7, 68, 117, 99, 107, 121, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 2, 4, -28, 0, 0, 2, 112, 0, 68, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 110, 0, 97, 0, 32, 0, 83, 0, 105, 0, 109, 0, 112, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 117, 0, 115, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 112, 0, 117, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 99, 0, 107, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 32, 0, 115, 0, 105, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 104, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 112, 0, 97, 0, 121, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 109, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 121, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 117, 0, 112, 0, 108, 0, 111, 0, 97, 0, 100, 0, 32, 0, 118, 0, 105, 0, 100, 0, 101, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 108, 0, 105, 0, 112, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 111, 0, 102, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 101, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 79, 0, 108, 0, 100, 0, 32, 0, 66, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 100, 0, 103, 0, 101, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 78, 0, 101, 0, 119, 0, 32, 0, 74, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 101, 0, 121, 0, 46, 0, 46, 0, 46, 0, 68, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 110, 0, 97, 0, 32, 0, 83, 0, 105, 0, 109, 0, 112, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 117, 0, 115, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 112, 0, 117, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 99, 0, 107, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 32, 0, 115, 0, 105, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 104, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 112, 0, 97, 0, 121, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 109, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 121, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 117, 0, 112, 0, 108, 0, 111, 0, 97, 0, 100, 0, 32, 0, 118, 0, 105, 0, 100, 0, 101, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 108, 0, 105, 0, 112, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 111, 0, 102, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 101, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 79, 0, 108, 0, 100, 0, 32, 0, 66, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 100, 0, 103, 0, 101, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 78, 0, 101, 0, 119, 0, 32, 0, 74, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 101, 0, 121, 0, 32, 0, 74, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 56, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 50, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 48, 0, 46, 0, 32, 0, 83, 0, 105, 0, 109, 0, 112, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 52, 0, 50, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 119, 0, 104, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 119, 0, 101, 0, 105, 0, 103, 0, 104, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 109, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 104, 0, 97, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 54, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 32, 0, 112, 0, 111, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 100, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 40, 0, 50, 0, 55, 0, 50, 0, 32, 0, 107, 0, 103, 0, 41, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 110, 0, 100, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 105, 0, 109, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 97, 0, 99, 0, 104, 0, 32, 0, 49, 0, 44, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 32, 0, 112, 0, 111, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 100, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 40, 0, 52, 0, 53, 0, 53, 0, 32, 0, 107, 0, 103, 0, 41, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 119, 0, 97, 0, 103, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 97, 0, 109, 0, 112, 0, 97, 0, 105, 0, 103, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 98, 0, 101, 0, 99, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 119, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 108, 0, 100, 0, 39, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 97, 0, 118, 0, 105, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 108, 0, 105, 0, 118, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 32, 0, 119, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 97, 0, 110, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 100, 0, 109, 0, 105, 0, 116, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 104, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 115, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 104, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 114, 0, 121, 0, 32, 0, 102, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 110, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 115, 0, 104, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 102, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 99, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 101, 0, 45, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 99, 0, 104, 0, 32, 0, 102, 0, 111, 0, 111, 0, 100, 0, 46, 0, 32, 0, 80, 0, 105, 0, 99, 0, 116, 0, 117, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 97, 0, 107, 0, 101, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 74, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 56, 0, 44, 0, 32, 0, 50, 0, 48, 0, 49, 0, 48, 0, 46, 0, 32, 0, 82, 0, 69, 0, 85, 0, 84, 0, 69, 0, 82, 0, 83, 0, 47, 0, 76, 0, 117, 0, 99, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 74, 0, 97, 0, 99, 0, 107, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 40, 0, 85, 0, 78, 0, 73, 0, 84, 0, 69, 0, 68, 0, 32, 0, 83, 0, 84, 0, 65, 0, 84, 0, 69, 0, 83, 0, 32, 0, 45, 0, 32, 0, 84, 0, 97, 0, 103, 0, 115, 0, 58, 0, 32, 0, 72, 0, 69, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 84, 0, 72, 0, 32, 0, 83, 0, 79, 0, 67, 0, 73, 0, 69, 0, 84, 0, 89, 0, 41, 0, 0, -1, -37, 0, 67, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26, 28, 28, 32, 36, 46, 39, 32, 34, 44, 35, 28, 28, 40, 55, 41, 44, 48, 49, 52, 52, 52, 31, 39, 57, 61, 56, 50, 60, 46, 51, 52, 50, -1, -37, 0, 67, 1, 9, 9, 9, 12, 11, 12, 24, 13, 13, 24, 50, 33, 28, 33, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, -1, -64, 0, 17, 8, 1, 32, 1, -52, 3, 1, 34, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1, -1, -60, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -1, -60, 0, 76, 16, 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 5, 4, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 17, 0, 4, 5, 18, 33, 49, 6, 65, 81, 19, 34, 97, 113, -127, -111, 20, 50, -95, 7, 66, -79, -63, -16, 21, 35, 82, -47, 36, 51, 98, 114, -126, -94, -31, -15, 22, 83, -62, -46, 37, 99, -110, -109, -78, 8, 115, 52, 53, 68, 85, 100, -77, -30, -1, -60, 0, 26, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -60, 0, 45, 17, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 17, 3, 33, 18, 49, 4, 65, 81, 19, 34, 97, 113, -79, -16, 20, -111, -47, 5, 35, 50, 66, -95, -31, -1, -38, 0, 12, 3, 1, 0, 2, 17, 3, 17, 0, 63, 0, -21, -96, -17, 64, -11, -92, -125, 74, -98, -75, -56, 116, 7, -17, 71, -52, -46, 65, -97, 10, 85, 0, 40, 80, -102, 33, 52, 40, 1, 92, -7, 82, 78, -44, 13, 36, -21, 64, 7, 67, -42, -109, 71, 64, 7, -46, -114, -109, -45, 106, 51, 64, 2, -116, -47, 80, 39, 77, 77, 0, 42, -118, -123, 9, -96, 3, -94, -10, -95, -25, 68, 117, -38, -104, 7, 66, -118, 104, 82, 0, 80, -95, -27, 69, 76, 0, 104, -89, -91, 3, 69, 64, 7, -67, 23, -67, 9, -94, -25, 64, 3, -34, -116, -111, 73, 49, 52, 9, 20, 0, 40, -113, -42, -118, -121, -122, -76, -64, 26, -46, 105, 81, 69, 20, -128, 17, -54, -123, 8, -93, -118, 64, 20, 82, -94, -124, 82, -128, -96, 4, -88, 119, 23, -24, 40, -109, 78, 44, 119, 21, 61, 69, 36, 10, 98, 22, -102, 113, 59, 82, 6, -44, -32, -90, -124, 56, 41, 66, -110, 41, 66, -87, 0, -79, 71, 69, 70, 61, 106, -47, 33, -51, 28, -47, 80, -96, 66, -88, -26, -109, 64, 26, 0, 57, -42, -114, 105, 51, 66, 105, 5, 11, -102, 20, -112, 124, 69, 29, 0, 42, -118, 104, 10, 28, -88, 0, 81, 107, 71, 66, -99, 0, 40, 81, 80, -102, 64, 84, -125, -46, -107, 34, -112, 15, -123, 43, 88, -48, 86, 38, -95, -119, -91, -45, 114, 121, -46, -3, -88, 0, -63, -93, -102, 42, 20, 0, 9, -92, -88, -47, -103, -92, 19, -50, -128, 20, 40, 77, 36, 31, 42, 19, -42, -128, 21, 52, 116, -119, -93, -15, -96, 5, 80, 59, 122, -47, 10, 7, 97, -74, -30, -128, 21, 52, 38, -109, 71, 64, 7, 66, -110, 77, 28, -48, 1, -48, -102, 76, -48, -96, 3, -102, 34, 104, 81, 19, 64, 2, -123, 10, 34, 69, 48, 4, -47, 19, 66, -128, -96, 2, 62, -76, -103, -91, 30, -76, -104, -90, 0, 20, 98, -120, 80, 19, 72, 5, 77, 39, -54, -124, -51, 21, 0, 44, 80, -46, -117, 125, -23, 67, 90, 64, 24, 20, -80, 5, 36, 68, -46, -58, -76, -60, 18, -57, 113, 95, -34, 20, -108, -118, 91, -122, 19, 29, 85, -7, 82, 69, 0, 44, 82, -59, 32, 82, -59, 52, 38, 44, 82, -123, 32, 82, -22, -48, -123, 81, -118, 64, -91, 77, 82, 1, 84, 116, 83, 66, -104, -125, -25, 67, -107, 21, 0, 117, -92, 1, -125, 66, 104, -124, -64, -95, 53, 32, 40, 116, -93, -92, -47, -118, 96, 42, 69, 9, -94, -95, 62, 84, 8, 30, -15, -46, -114, -118, 104, 72, -102, 96, 15, 57, -94, -34, -124, -47, 122, -48, 5, 35, 119, -115, 56, -128, -76, 25, 73, -25, 75, 23, 41, -102, -95, -78, 37, 41, 82, 12, 127, 16, -4, -22, 88, -41, 104, -84, 104, -44, -79, 114, -19, 73, 0, 54, -62, -100, 81, -97, -68, 18, 7, -103, -2, 64, -46, 62, 42, -20, 110, -59, -78, -68, 3, -85, 7, -36, -93, -14, -88, 15, 57, -39, 50, -73, 114, 41, 121, 6, 108, -88, 65, 82, -107, -32, 0, -44, -97, 42, -120, -116, 102, -43, 87, 1, -91, 118, -19, 44, -126, 66, 87, 106, -24, 49, -44, -9, 96, 122, -47, 64, -109, 52, 45, 92, -123, -50, 102, -36, 105, 67, 112, -79, -89, -95, 26, 31, -44, -45, -95, -44, -98, -66, -43, 66, 47, -112, -30, 101, -112, -91, 13, -91, 64, -89, -24, 105, 11, 122, -31, 99, -25, 41, 7, -110, 52, -94, -128, -48, 41, 99, -81, -91, 37, 74, 51, 89, -26, -46, -92, -72, 12, -86, 100, 107, 52, -1, 0, 15, 37, 45, 96, -84, -74, -128, 18, -128, -91, -108, -92, 108, 37, 68, -97, -87, 38, -114, -128, -71, -111, 66, 105, -68, -38, 81, -51, 32, 28, -109, 67, 53, 34, 122, -5, 81, -125, 64, 14, 77, 2, 118, -13, 20, -119, -91, 125, -47, -3, -31, 52, 0, -70, 42, 41, 52, 38, -128, 12, -102, 20, -109, 66, -104, 10, -96, 77, 36, -102, 18, 104, 1, 83, 68, 72, -25, 73, -102, 19, 64, 7, 52, 71, 78, -108, 38, -123, 0, 20, -7, -47, -47, 81, -19, 69, -128, 41, 42, -93, -92, -109, -19, 64, 21, 92, 65, -60, -104, 95, 12, -39, 11, -84, 73, -41, 6, 109, 27, 101, -122, -13, -72, -28, 111, 3, 64, 7, -119, 32, 120, -51, 115, 59, -1, 0, -74, -53, -27, -87, 67, 9, -64, -20, -38, 108, 24, 11, -67, 121, 110, -85, -52, -124, 101, 3, -36, -7, -42, -17, -120, -101, -73, -65, -62, -18, 123, 118,
-112, -76, 40, 110, -95, 48, 6, -43, -61, 113, -101, 70, -84, -18, 22, -106, -13, -72, -127, -79, 73, 76, 15, 45,
-87, -82, -10...
```

and at end of this byte array im getting this 3 dots and array is not completed ,so how can i get correct byte array

base64 string is

```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...
```

also tried for Mutipart entity

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("My url");
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "top.jpg");
            // File file= new File("/mnt/sdcard/forest.png");
            // FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("PhotoImage", bab);
           // reqEntity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody("sfsdfsdf"));
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
```

sending encoded string to web service

```
 private void HttpCon_PhotoUpload()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL1);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Photo",encodedImage));
            Log.d("req", "req" + nameValuePairs);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d("response", "response" + response);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1","connection success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.d("aaa","aaa" + result);
            Log.e("pass 2","connection success ");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

webservice response :

```
Cannot convert _9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL_2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL_wAARCAeMChADASIAAhEBAxEB_8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL_8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4-Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3-Pn6_8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL_8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3-Pn6_9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDwcj2pevJ5NOZsnpQD14pbCRHyTzRTs8dKQng0wGHqRTlozSZoCwUh6UtB5oGNApelAxmjvQAbuKQ0ZoBpDuGTQOaU80g4pCFC5oPFIOKXPrTATOaD0pe9GaYBnik6Gj8KXIApAJnJpRSKQaXFNAA65pRwelJQDz0pABOaUHFIQCKOlAC5OaMUmacCQtAho... to System.Byte.
Parameter name: type ---> Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: Logcat does not print out full data if it is too long. Hence, your data may be already correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into byte array and byte array to base64 String in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513976/how-to-convert-image-into-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-base64-string-in-android)

Comment: i want to post that string to webservice and there i m not getting proper response on server

Comment: @ varun m facing same issue , the answer not cleared my problem

Comment: if you are sending image as param or header , then better use multipart meaning split byte array to multiple parts and combine on server end

Comment: Also used updated code still facing the problem

Comment: `result im getting is

[-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16,` It is pretty unclear how you obtained those figures. And why are you printing the values of the bytes as signed? Bytes are unsigned. And is this on the server? Or where?

Comment: You did not show how you send that base64 string to your server.

Comment: Updated question includes , m sending "encodedImage" string to webservice

Answer (score 0):

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    tools:context="com.android_examples.imageuploadonserver_android_examplescom.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK HERE TO CAPTURE IMAGE "
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_margin="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@drawable/input_selector"
        android:hint="Enter Image Name Here"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK HERE TO UPLOAD IMAGE"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
       />





</LinearLayout>
```

Class File Where i capture and upload an image to server ::

```
public class PhotoUploadDemo extends ActionBarActivity
{

    Button GetImageFromGalleryButton, UploadImageOnServerButton;
    ImageView ShowSelectedImage;
    EditText GetImageName;
    Bitmap FixBitmap;
    String ImageTag = "image_tag" ;
    String ImageName = "image_data" ;
    String ServerUploadPath ="ServerPath/URL" ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream ;
    byte[] byteArray ;
    String ConvertImage ;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    String GetImageNameFromEditText;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection ;
    URL url;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;
    int RC ;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    boolean check = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_upload_demo);

        GetImageFromGalleryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        UploadImageOnServerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ShowSelectedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        GetImageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        GetImageFromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try
                    {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null)
                    {
                        GetImageName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //carry out the crop operation
                        //   performCrop();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,100);
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        UploadImageOnServerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                GetImageNameFromEditText = GetImageName.getText().toString();
                UploadImageToServer();
            }
        });



    }//EOF OnCreate

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException
    {
        // Create an image file name
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("Getpath", "Cool" + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            //Set Pic to imageview
            setPic();
        }
    }
    //set Pic to
    private void setPic()
    {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = ShowSelectedImage.getWidth();
        int targetH = ShowSelectedImage.getHeight();
        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        FixBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
    }

    public void UploadImageToServer()
    {
        FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PhotoUploadDemo.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(string1);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(PhotoUploadDemo.this, string1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();
                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
                //  HashMapParams.put(ImageTag, GetImageNameFromEditText);
                HashMapParams.put("Photo1", ConvertImage);
                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(ServerUploadPath,HashMapParams);
                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
        AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
    }//EOF Upload OnServer Method



    public class ImageProcessClass
    {
        public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                url = new URL(requestURL);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String RC2;
                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet())
            {
                if (check)
                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilder.append("&");
                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(),"UTF-8"));
                stringBuilder.append("=");
                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(),"UTF-8"));
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }




}//EOF Main
```